# Calculate financial indicators on live prices

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Supposing you have the current price (current live price) and its history, is it possible to calculate indicators such as RSI, MACD, etc ... at any time? I am using python and the pandas library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, I am sure there are plenty of API's from finance websites that can give you that data exactly, so you would not even need to calculate.

But if you prefer, as long as you have the data, absolutely.

Comment: many formulas that I find on the internet, however, refer to data that I do not have and do not want to consider for now, such as the "close price", how do I do in that case?

Comment: So, you can actually use some free API's, like the yahoo finance python API, and I believe it scrapes and provides you the data for free. otherwise, you may have to pay for API calls if you subscribe to a finance website with a datafeed or has live data some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have the data it is very easy to do simply find the formulas on investopedia or another well known finance website and you can go from there!